# Connecting USB 3.1 front panel to USB 3.2 motherboard connector

Tags: usb, computer-building, usb-3

My computer case, "[Corsair 4000D Airflow](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Cases/Mid-Tower-ATX-Cases/4000D-Airflow-Tempered-Glass-Mid-Tower-ATX-Case/p/CC-9011200-WW)" has a front panel with:

- **USB 3.1 Type-C** port
- **USB 3.0 Type-A** port

[image: Illustration of the front panel cable connectors on the 4000D airflow]

I am considering buying the motherboard [Asus Prime x299 Edition 30](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/Prime-X299-Edition-30/). But since the motherboard is newer, it doesn't have USB 3.1 connectors. Instead it features the newer USB 3.2 standard.

It has one connector for USB 3.2 **Gen2**:

[image: Screenshot from the Asus Prime x299 Edition 30 User manual]

And one connector for USB 3.2 **Gen1**:

[image: Screenshot from the Asus Prime x299 Edition 30 User manual]

So the question is:

Should I try to connect the USB **3.1** cable from the Corsair case to the USB **3.2** connectors on the motherboard? Will I break something? Will it work?

**Edit: After having built this setp i can confirm that this works**

Comment: As far as I know there exists only two different connectors, the "old" I would call USB 3.0 (also labeled USB 3.0 on your first picture) and the "new" connector type for USB-C sockets. Your confusion is caused by USB organization which has re-labeled the USB standards several times... (USB 3.2 Gen 1 == USB 3.1)

Comment: “it doesn't have USB 3.1 connectors.” - Yes; It actually does. USB 3.2 Gen 1 is USB 3.1 Gen 1.  Additionally, both those connectors are identical.  FYI:USB 3.1 Gen 1 is USB 3.0

Comment: OK I think I get it. USB 3.2 Gen1 is the same as USB 3.1 Gen1. It's just that different manufacturers use different names that are the same thing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-6rd0jGsF4

Comment: @Robert Please provide this as an answer. It works and it is a very good answer.

Comment: "USB 3.2 Gen2" will fit for "USB 3.1 Type-C", and "USB 3.2 Gen1" will fit for "USB 3.0". It doesn't really have anything to do with the "3.x". They are simply different types of connectors and the former ones are for providing a (probably just one) type-c port. (They are sometimes called "usb type-e" on the market for some reasons. It's probably not an official name though. Not even sure if the connectors themselves were ever standardized.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there exists only three different USB connectors for mainboards:

1. USB 2.0 connector
2. Connector for "USB 3.0" (also labeled USB 3.0 in your first picture).
3. Connector for USB-C (named USB 3.1 Type-C" in your first picture).

Your confusion is caused by USB-IF which has renamed the USB standards several times so that USB 3.0 is also known as "USB 3.1 Gen1" or "USB 3.2 Gen 1" or "SuperSpeed USB".